# How can others run my docker image from my local network?

Tags: docker

I've successfully created (**using ubuntu VB**) a docker image

What would be the best approach to let others from my local network run that image using ssh? I've been searching for quite some time and couldn't find anything that'd help.

I believe I have to map to a port somehow using the dockerfile and forward that port from my VM to my actual OS, but I don't know exactly how to do it or if it that's how is supposed to be done.

Any tips at all would be great help

TL;DR: Created a docker image using an ubuntu VB and I want others from my local network to be able to use it using ssh

Comment: Ideally you should be using a docker management tool (like swarm/kubernetes) etc to manage you containers, but if you just want to start you container and expose it to others, you can simply start your container by running this command docker run -d -p 4022:22 your_docker_image ( supposing the sshd service inside the container is running on port 22 and you want to expose it on port 4022 )

Comment: I've tried that and the container ends within seconds of the execution, which is to be expected considering the app just prints something. I tried to use docker start [container_id] --attach but to no avail.  Could you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: Can you paste your docker file here ?

Comment: FROM python:3; ADD my_script.py / ; EXPOSE 9300; CMD ['python", "./my_script.py" ]

Comment: Can you also provide me your script.py. your docker container will exit if the  main process finishes and this seems to be a case with your script.

Comment: it does, it's a simple print. I've used tail /dev/null so the container doesn't close itself.

Comment: So, is it workiworking fine now after you added tail /dev/null?

Comment: The container doesn't stop anymore but I still couldn't make it work. As in doing localhost:9300 won't work and the port is not seen on the windows (host of VM)

Comment: That won't work for obvious reasons. Are you running a linux machine as a vm on virtualbox and your host OS is windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, made it work, here is how I did it:

1. Run the image
2. Use `docker port [containerID] 80`, to see the port of the running computer
3. [Port forward that port from VirtualBox
   settings](https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/)
4. Set inbound / outbound rules for that specific port from windows firewall settings